# Finding a similar matrix sequence under some constraints

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve a problem where I want the product of a sequence of row stochastic matrices $\prod_{t=1}^{T}A(t) \times 1_n^T$ to be as close as possible to the product of another sequence of row stochastic matrices $\prod_{t=1}^{T}B(t) \times 1_n^T$. That is, the goal is to minimize $ |\prod_{t=1}^{T}A(t) \times 1_n^T - \prod_{t=1}^{T}B(t) \times 1_n^T|$. Here B(t) and A(t) have a similar structure and are $n
\times n$ matrices and $1_n = \begin{bmatrix} 1, 1, 1,\ldots, 1\end{bmatrix}$. As an example, for n = 3, the structure looks like this :
Matrix A(t) or B(t) = \begin{bmatrix}1-\frac{2u_1(t)}{3} & \frac{u_1(t)}{3} & \frac{u_1(t)}{3}\\\frac{u_2(t)}{3} & 1-\frac{2u_2(t)}{3} & \frac{u_2(t)}{3}\\ \frac{u_3(t)}{3} & \frac{u_3(t)}{3}& 1-\frac{2u_3(t)}{3}\end{bmatrix}

Here $u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t) = \{0,1\} \forall t$ . Now the bit pattern sequence $u_1(t), u_2(t), u_3(t)$ corresponding to matrix B(t) have no constraints. That is the sequence $u_1(1), u_1(2), \ldots u_1(10)$ for $t = 1,2,3,\ldots 10$ corresponding to matrix B can be $0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0$. But $u_1(t)$ corresponding to matrix A(t) must have a periodic pattern. It can have any phase shift in the beginning and any period, i.e. valid $u_1(t)$ corresponding to A can be $0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0$ for $t = 1,2,\ldots 10$ . Here phase shift is 4 and period is 2.

Now the objective is to find the correct phase shift and delay for the bit sequence of all rows of A matrix that will minimize the product as mentioned earlier. I appreciate any suggestions or pointers for approaching this problem efficiently.